# Настройка отправки почты с сайта (БЕЗ использования PHPMailer!)

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

Почта с сервера, отправленная мне или другим людям, приходит в спам.

Я настроил SPF, DKIM, DMARC на сервере своем (web-hosting). Проверил, что все правильно работает - тут -
 https://dmarcguide.globalcyberalliance.org

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почта все равно приходит в спам. Люди советуют добавить что-то в Header или настроить SMTP, но все они пишут про библиотеку "PHPMailer". . Пытаюсь найти варианты решения без использования той библиотеки.

Что мне нужно настроить в header (если надо)?
Как мне добавить SMTP (если требуется).

читал, что в smtp надо писать, например:

- smtp.google.com
- port: 25, 465, or 587
- почта и пароль

Обязательно ли это вводить в код PHP? Не могут ли злоумышленники перехватить мой email и пароль, который я пропишу в коде отправки емэйла с сервера себе на почту?

Comment: 1. Почему все таки не эта либа? Она достаточно мощная. 2. Не смогут перехватить, ведь скрипт никак не отображает эти данные на странице, в БД точно хранить не нужно.

Comment: @DaemonHK Думал, можно без нее обойтись

Comment: то есть даже ссылаясь на ту страницу php с отправкой эмейла - злоумышленники не получат к ней доступ...

Comment: $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'passwordxxx'
    ));

Comment: @DaemonHK ТО есть это, написанное в PHP не попадет никому? Мне просто интересно, потому что никогда не задумывался об безопасности. Потому что я знаю, что

Comment: PHP просто исполняется на сервере, если данные никакие не выводятся принудительно (print_r, var_dump, echo, print), а также отключен вывод ошибок (никогда так не делайте) или попросту ошибок нет, то на странице ничего не отобразится. Доступ к скриптам тогда возможно получить только через FTP, но тут все зависит от сложности пароля, рукожопости админов хостинг-провайдера. В общем, в 99,99% случаев даже не думайте об этом.

Comment: @DaemonHK если бы у Бога было имя - он бы звался тобою) Спасибо, что "успокоил"

Comment: я атеист)) по остальным вопросам что решили?